# Collection out of a nested HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have a little problem with my following code considering a NullPointerException:

```
@Override
public List<FlowEdge<V>> getEdges() {
    List<FlowEdge<V>> edges = new ArrayList<FlowEdge<V>>();
    Collection<FlowEdge<V>> collection = new ArrayList<>();
    collection = graph.get(getNodes()).values();
    edges.addAll(collection);
    return edges;
}
```

I know this could be written a little shorter but I wanted to split the code a little to find out where I get the NullPointerException. So the problem is in the line with "collection =...".

Graph is a nested HashMap:

`Map<V, Map<V, FlowEdge<V>> graph = new HashMap<>();`

and getNodes() is a method returning a set inside the same class. I already testet if getNodes() provides an empty set and this wasn't the case.

```
@Override
public Set<V> getNodes() {
    Set<V> set = graph.keySet();
    return set; 
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no sense in the initialization `collection = new ArrayList<>();` when you overwrite the variable like `collection = graph.get(getNodes()).values();` right in the next line. Besides that, if that line proves a `NullPointerException`, one of the values dereferenced in that line must be `null`, either `graph` or the value returned by `get`. When `graph` is the same `graph` as in the `getNodes()` method, you are doing `graph.get(graph.keySet())` which makes no sense and will always return `null`.

Answer (score 2):

The key of the `graph` Map is of type `V`, so passing a `Set<V>` to that `Map`'s `get()` method will always return `null`.

If you want to obtain all the `FlowEdge<V>` values of the inner `Map`s, you can write something like this:

```
List<FlowEdge<V>> collection =
    graph.values() // a Collection<Map<V, FlowEdge<V>>
         .stream() // a Stream<Map<V, FlowEdge<V>>
         .flatMap(m -> m.values().stream()) // a Stream<FlowEdge<V>>
         .collect(Collectors.toList()); // a List<FlowEdge<V>>
```

EDIT:

Note that the above snippet is a single statement. It is only divided into multiple lines for readability.

The same can be written in a single line of code:

```
List<FlowEdge<V>> collection = graph.values().stream().flatMap(m -> m.values().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: With values() it says:

```Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collection<Map<V,FlowEdge<V>>> to List<FlowEdge<V>>```

With .stream() it says:

``` The method stream() is undefined for the type Map<V,Map<V,FlowEdge<V>>>```

With .flatMap(...) it says:

```The method flatMap((<no type> m) -> {}) is undefined for the type Map<V,Map<V,FlowEdge<V>>>```

With .collect(...) it says:

``` The method collect(Collectors.toList()) is undefined for the type Map<V,Map<V,FlowEdge<V>>> ```

These are already other approaches but unfortunately still no solutions. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse with openJDK 12.0.2 (which is what I have to use in this project)

Comment: @Peerius this answer shows you *one* solution that you should use as a whole, not four solutions that you have to try one after another.

Comment: @Holger oh, so that's what the OP meant in that comment. I'll clarify my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Eran well, I deduced it from the error messages that are impossible to get when using your code as-is (and impossible to get them all at the same time).

Comment: @Holger yes, that makes sense.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't get that.. I will try this when I'm home and test if it works in that way.